# Pivot data down instead of flattening in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have Json --

```
[
    {
        "label": "EL04_AA02_P2064_12588",
        "uri": "http://www.awer.com/onasdgfgies/addhh.rdf#i613b844f9b503172424717ebbfa5f73098",
        "updated_at": "2022-07-27 09:16:43",
        "interactionData": [
            {
                "type": "Choice",
                "nb choice": 4,
                "responseIdentifier": "RESPONSE_A",
                "BR_identifier": "choice_2",
                "BR_label": "chronological order",
                "choice_identifier_1": "choice_1",
                "choice_label_1": "problem and solution",
                "choice_identifier_2": "choice_2",
                "choice_label_2": "chronological order",
                "choice_identifier_3": "choice_3",
                "choice_label_3": "cause and effect ",
                "choice_identifier_4": "choice_4",
                "choice_label_4": "comparison of ideas"
            },
            {
                "type": "Choice",
                "nb choice": 6,
                "responseIdentifier": "RESPONSE_B",
                "BR_identifier": "choice_8|choice_13",
                "BR_label": "“In 1958, asdghfjgjjk asdghfjgjjk became NASA. Shortly thereafter, asdghfjgjjk became part of the space team.” (paragraph 7)|“In September 1962, President John F. Kennedy charged the country to send a man to the Moon.” (paragraph 8)",
                "choice_identifier_1": "choice_5",
                "choice_label_1": "“asdghfjgjjk was an asdghfjgjjk asdghfjgjjk who worked for asdghfjgjjk from 1953 until 1986.” (paragraph 1)",
                "choice_identifier_2": "choice_6",
                "choice_label_2": "“asdghfjgjjk was the name of the asdghfjgjjk agency that later became asdghfjgjjk.” (paragraph 4)",
                "choice_identifier_3": "choice_7",
                "choice_label_3": "“asdghfjgjjk.” (paragraph 5)",
                "choice_identifier_4": "choice_8",
                "choice_label_4": "“In 1958, asdghfjgjjk asdghfjgjjk became asdghfjgjjk. Shortly thereafter, asdghfjgjjk became part of the space team.” (paragraph 7)",
                "choice_identifier_5": "choice_13",
                "choice_label_5": "“asdghfjgjjk.” (paragraph 8)",
                "choice_identifier_6": "choice_14",
                "choice_label_6": "“to orbit.” (paragraph 8)"
            }
        ],
        "Task Model": "4B.1: Analyzing the relationship between a series of concepts",
        "Common Core State Standard ID": "RI.4.5 4.1 Refer to d.",
        "Evidence Statement": "RI 4.1.1: .",
        "ELA Item Key": "",
        "Number of Points": "2",
        "Scoring Rules": "EBSR - 1A,2+E",
        "Item Type": "EBSR",
        "Task Type": "RST",
        "Text Complexity": "Medium",
        "CC4 Processing Demands": "Medium",
        "CC3 Response Mode": "High",
        "CC2 Command of Textual Evidence": "Medium",
        "EOY Informational Category": "Reading Informational Text",
        "Claim/Sub-Claim": "Reading - Informational Text",
        "Item Set Sequence": "3",
        "Item Passage Sequence": "",
        "Associated Passage": "Who Was asdghfjgjjk",
        "Passage Group": "asdghfjgjjk",
        "Passage Set ID": "P2064",
        "Grade": "Grade 4",
        "Status Comments": "",
        "Original UIN": "EL04_AA02_P2064_12588",
        "Interaction Type IL": "",
        "Operational": "",
        "Field Test": "",
        "Workflow Status": "09. Ready for Committee Review",
        "Phases": "Year 2",
        "Item Key": "B|D,E",
        "5-Digit UIN": "12588",
        "Item_Writer_ID": "CAE04",
        "Multimedia": "No",
        "Release Year": "",
        "Scoring Rubric or Rationale": "B|D,E",
        "Dependent Item": "",
        "Scoring Mode": "",
        "Alt Files": "",
        "Exclude Accessibility Support Features": "",
        "Accessibility Support Features": "",
        "Item Enemy": "",
        "Art": "",
        "Delivery Mode": "Paper|Computer",
        "Cognitive Complexity": "Medium",
        "Bank": "Illinois",
        "Subject": "ELA",
        "Asset Type": "Item",
        "State": "",
        "assets": [
            {
                "Label": "EL04_AA02_RST_P2064-0_Scenario",
                "Asset_Developer_ID": "",
                "Original UIN": "",
                "Content Type": "",
                "Grade": "",
                "Graphics/Multimedia Revisions Requested": "",
                "Graphic_Alt_Tags": "",
                "Academic Course": [],
                "Passage/Stimulus Set ID": "",
                "Paired Passage/Stimulus": "",
                "Passage/Stimulus Set Title": "",
                "Passage/Stimulus Set Sequence": "",
                "Asset Workflow Status": "",
                "Passage/Stimulus A Title": "",
                "Passage/Stimulus A ID": "",
                "Item Passage/Stimulus Sequence": [],
                "Passage/Stimulus B Title": "",
                "Phases": "",
                "Passage/Stimulus B ID": "",
                "Passage/Stimulus C Title": "",
                "Passage/Stimulus C ID": "",
                "Passage Type": "",
                "Author Name": "",
                "EOY Informational Category": "",
                "Genre": [],
                "Length Designation": "",
                "Text Complexity Analysis": "",
                "Word Count": "",
                "Lexile": "",
                "Flesch-Kincaid": "",
                "RMM": "",
                "Glossed Terms": "",
                "Gender Representation in Text": "",
                "Multi-Cultural Passage": "",
                "Author Gender": "",
                "Text Selection": "",
                "Number of Art Pieces": "",
                "Text Complexity": "",
                "Task Type": "",
                "Copyright": "",
                "Delivery Mode": [],
                "Copyright Type": "",
                "Art": "",
                "CCC Number": "",
                "Source": "",
                "Copyright Source Text": "",
                "Rights": [],
                "Text Permissions Notes": "",
                "Art Permissions": "",
                "State": "",
                "PkgHref": "",
                "PkgIdentifier": "",
                "Language": "English",
                "Alternative Text": "EL04_AA02_RST_P2064-0_Scenario",
                "uri": "http://www.awer.com/onasdgfgies/addhh.rdf#i613b844f9b503172424717ebbfa5f73098",
                "identifier": "i61af6b75e5c4c14293c665e5dc1199871a",
                "updated_at": "2022-03-30 07:02:29"
            },
            {
                "Label": "EL04_AA02_RST_P2064-1_WhoWasKatherineasdghfjgjjk",
                "Asset_Developer_ID": "",
                "Original UIN": "",
                "Content Type": "",
                "Grade": "",
                "Graphics/Multimedia Revisions Requested": "",
                "Graphic_Alt_Tags": "",
                "Academic Course": [],
                "Passage/Stimulus Set ID": "",
                "Paired Passage/Stimulus": "",
                "Passage/Stimulus Set Title": "",
                "Passage/Stimulus Set Sequence": "",
                "Asset Workflow Status": "",
                "Passage/Stimulus A Title": "",
                "Passage/Stimulus A ID": "",
                "Item Passage/Stimulus Sequence": [],
                "Passage/Stimulus B Title": "",
                "Phases": "",
                "Passage/Stimulus B ID": "",
                "Passage/Stimulus C Title": "",
                "Passage/Stimulus C ID": "",
                "Passage Type": "",
                "Author Name": "",
                "EOY Informational Category": "",
                "Genre": [],
                "Length Designation": "",
                "Text Complexity Analysis": "",
                "Word Count": "",
                "Lexile": "",
                "Flesch-Kincaid": "",
                "RMM": "",
                "Glossed Terms": "",
                "Gender Representation in Text": "",
                "Multi-Cultural Passage": "",
                "Author Gender": "",
                "Text Selection": "",
                "Number of Art Pieces": "",
                "Text Complexity": "",
                "Task Type": "",
                "Copyright": "",
                "Delivery Mode": [],
                "Copyright Type": "",
                "Art": "",
                "CCC Number": "",
                "Source": "",
                "Copyright Source Text": "",
                "Rights": [],
                "Text Permissions Notes": "",
                "Art Permissions": "",
                "State": "",
                "PkgHref": "",
                "PkgIdentifier": "",
                "Language": "English",
                "Alternative Text": "EL04_AA02_RST_P2064-1_WhoWasKatherineasdghfjgjjk",
                "uri": "http://www.awer.com/onasdgfgies/addhh.rdf#i613b844f9b503172424717ebbfa5f73098",
                "identifier": "i613b844f9b503172424717ebbfa5f73098",
                "updated_at": "2022-05-23 01:36:53"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Want to transform like below--

[image]

using below link to convert same to csv. selecting  **Pivot data down instead of flattening  option**.
https://www.convertcsv.com/json-to-csv.htm same i want to write transformation. Could you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure why you want to use PIVOT when flatten works really nicely

Ah that was the  thing to do in the online tool...

```
select f1.value:uri as uri
    ,f1.value:updated_at as updated_at
    ,f2.value:type as "interactionData//0//type"
    ,f2.value:"nb choice" as "interactionData//0//nu choice"
    ,f2.value:responseIdentifier as "interactionData//0//responseIdentifier"
from data
    ,table(flatten(input=>data.json)) as f1
    ,table(flatten(input=>f1.value:interactionData)) as f2
```

gives:

| URI | UPDATED_AT | interactionData//0//type | interactionData//0//nu choice | interactionData//0//responseIdentifier |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "http://www.awer.com/onasdgfgies/addhh.rdf#i613b844f9b503172424717ebbfa5f73098" | "2022-07-27 09:16:43" | "Choice" | 4 | "RESPONSE_A" |
| "http://www.awer.com/onasdgfgies/addhh.rdf#i613b844f9b503172424717ebbfa5f73098" | "2022-07-27 09:16:43" | "Choice" | 6 | "RESPONSE_B" |

albeit, I would cast those values to types like:

```
select f1.value:uri::text as uri
    ,f1.value:updated_at::timestamp_ntz as updated_at
    ,f2.value:type::text as "interactionData//0//type"
    ,f2.value:"nb choice"::number as "interactionData//0//nu choice"
    ,f2.value:responseIdentifier::text as "interactionData//0//responseIdentifier"
from data
    ,table(flatten(input=>data.json)) as f1
    ,table(flatten(input=>f1.value:interactionData)) as f2
```

Comment: @ Simeon Pilgrim ,Could you please help me there is one more level "assets" I am wring query like below--

Comment: select
    f1.value:label::string as label
    ,f2.value:type::text as "interactionData_type"
    ,f2.value:responseIdentifier::string as "interactionData_responseIdentifier"
    ,f3.value:"Label"::string as Label
    ,f3.value:"Asset_Developer_ID"::string as Asset_Developer_ID
   from ITEM_METADATA_JSON j
   ,table( flatten(input=>j.JSON_FIELD)) as f1
   ,table(flatten(input=>f1.value:interactionData)) as f2
   ,table( flatten(input=>f1.value:assets)) as f3;

Comment: How i can get 2 rows as this query giving me 4 row

Comment: it is not apparent just from your new example SQL, how you would like to fold these `f3` values together.

Comment: looking at those blobs, `Label`/`Alt Text`/`Identifier`/`Update_At` are the only this different between the two assets blocks. You could use a QUALIFY to take the later of the 2+ assets.

Comment: I want two rows from "Assets" corresponding to each label(main) same as interactionData. my query making 4 as its joining for each row in json

Comment: I want two rows from "Assets" corresponding to each label(main) same as interactionData. my query making 4 as its joining for each row in json. Distinct is not working here as from f3 its joining for EL04_AA02_RST_P2064-0_Scenario and 
EL04_AA02_RST_P2064-1_WhoWasKatherineJohnson to each interactionData_nu choice (4,6) .

Comment: Yes get outcome of the f3 flatten. You have the option to filter via WHERE clause or QUALIFY clause if there is a dynamic rule that can identify whic of the 2+ block you want. Whereas if you know there will always be 2 block and you only want the first you can avoid the third flatten and just access the array directly off the `f2.value:assest[0]`